# How to pass `null` to httpBody of URLRequest Swift?

Tags: swift, swift5, urlrequest

How can I set the `httpBody` for a `URLRequest` to `null`? (like the image below taken from Postman).

[image]

I have verified that the call ONLY works in Postman if the body is actually set to `null` (raw JSON) as seen in the above. If the body is empty, or set to none, it fails (with a 415 error code if that matters to you).

My code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://my-url.com/other/stuff") else { return nil }
var deleteRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
deleteRequest.httpMethod = "DELETE"

// I have tried all of these and they do not work
deleteRequest.httpBody = nil
deleteRequest.httpBody = Data()
deleteRequest.httpBody = ""
deleteRequest.httpBody = "null".data(using: .utf8)
deleteRequest.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: "", options: .fragmentsAllowed)
deleteRequest.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: NSNull(), options: .fragmentsAllowed)
```

PS: Unfortunately I can't share any more specific details about the request due to privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Turns out I needed to set the content-type to "application/json" like so: `deleteRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Setting the `.httpBody` to anything is completely unneeded then.